# After a share activity I initiate is complete, the application used during share opens instead of my own application

Tags: java, android

this is the code below I am using. What I am trying to do is I am sharing the text in edText (TextView) using email, sms, facebook etc applications.

The problem is, after sharing the text when I tried to re-open my application, the last chosed application opens(Like email, message, facebook application).

```
Intent intentf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentf.setType(text/plain);
intentf.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, edText.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentf, "Share with"));
```

How do I get my own application to reopen?

Answer (score 0):

Because your app is now "using" that app as an editor. If you hit back or are done with sharing you will return to your app.
If you look at the recent apps list, your icon will be displayed but with the shared app editor screen image showing. Same for all apps, try it with the browser for example and share as an email.

Comment: I know and I want to use it as an aditor but I want my application comes first when I re-open my app, as well. Is there a way to do so? if not, what should I do?

Comment: Thank you Mattias, but there should be some way to do that and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: If the user leaves the app at that point, the user expects to return where he/she left. As with any other screen in your app. If you close the app manually in the recent apps list (swipe it to the side), it won't remember where you were in the app and will start with the main activity again.

Comment: But if I chose Sms to send my text, then send my text using sms application, not using back button but using home button to go out of the sms app.(Which means I am done with sms app) when I click my app, it goes where it was last (sms App).

Comment: No it doesn't mean you are done with SMS app if you hit the home button, it means you leave it where it was and switch to the launcher app (home). Just as you would switch to another app in the recent apps list.

Comment: Thank you Mattias, for your time and affort to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't about solving the problem but how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase somebody may have the same problem.
I add 
    finish();
at the end of my code which ended my activity and that solved my problem.

Comment: That will stop you activity though. If that is the main activity you will have exited your app. If not it will return to your previous activity. That might or might not be what you intended. Good that added your own answer here by the way.